# Persisting class A with list of instances of A

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

Take a look at the following code sample.

```
    @PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable="true") 
    public class A implements Serializable
    {
        @PrimaryKey  
        @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)  
        @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")  
        private String key;
        @Persistent
        private String m_Name;
        @Persistent(mappedBy = "m_A")
        private List<B> m_ListOfB;
//...
    }



       @PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION,detachable="true") 
        public class B implements Serializable
        {
            @PrimaryKey
            @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
            @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
            private String key;
            @Persistent 
            private A m_A;
            @Persistent
        private List<B> m_Children;
//...
}
```

When i set up a instance of A, with a few B's in the m_ListOfB-list (These B-instanced have a few Children aswell) and persist it, i only see A in my datastore viewer.
If i remove the m_Children from B, and try to persist A again, i see A and the objects in m_ListOfB's.

Persisted like this

```
A a = new A("a");
B b = new B("b");
b.add_to_children(new B("child_of_b"));
a.add_to_list(b);

PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
pm.makePersistent(a);
pm.close();
```

Lists are set up correctly in the constructors, and i have the default empty Ctor for Serializable not to fail.

Perhaps this is an issue of indexes?
The datastore-indexes.xml looks like this

```
<datastore-index kind="B" ancestor="true" source="manual">
        <property name="m_ListOfB_INTEGER_IDX" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>
```

Not sure how the index for m_Children should look, or if i even need to add it.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could post the code you wrote for persisting the objects.

Comment: I deleted my post because I had misread the question. Sorry

Comment: The datastore viewer is weak.  Your entities may be stored correctly even if they don't show up in the viewer at all.  You do not need to define any indices to store data.  Try writing some code that fetches the B objects and their children, and see if it works.  Sometimes it feels like working with the datastore requires a lot of faith!